# dj rest auth reset password sends raw html in email

Tags: django, dj-rest-auth

I use dj rest auth package and i have overrided the reset password email like this

in settings.py :

```
REST_AUTH_SERIALIZERS = {
'JWT_TOKEN_CLAIMS_SERIALIZER': 'account.token.TokenObtainPairSerializer',
'USER_DETAILS_SERIALIZER': 'account_profile.api.userupdate.UserSerializer',
'PASSWORD_RESET_SERIALIZER': 'account_profile.api.customemail.CustomPasswordResetSerializer'}
```

and in customemail.py :

```
class CustomPasswordResetSerializer(PasswordResetSerializer):
def save(self):
    request = self.context.get('request')
    # Set some values to trigger the send_email method.
    opts = {
        'use_https': request.is_secure(),
        #'from_email': 'noreply@mizbans.com',
        'from_email': getattr(settings, 'DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL'),
        'request': request,
        
        # here I have set my desired template to be used
        # don't forget to add your templates directory in settings to be found
        'email_template_name': 'password_reset_email.html'
    }

    opts.update(self.get_email_options())
    self.reset_form.save(**opts)
```

and in email.py :

```
class MyPasswordResetSerializer(PasswordResetSerializer):
context={'domain':settings.WEBSITE_DOMAIN,'site_name':'mizban'}

def get_email_options(self) :
  
    return {
        'email_template_name': 'password_reset_email.html',
        'context':'context'
    }
```

I put a sample html code in password_reset_email :

```
 <html>
    <body>
      <p>welcome to{{domain}}</p>
      <p>site {{site_name}}</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

It works but it sends html tages codes as well in email template!

Comment: Use `{% autoescape off %} your html template here` {% endautoescape %}

Comment: still the same!

Comment: How do you construct your `mail_content` variable ? you need to use `render_to_string`

Comment: `from django.template.loader import render_to_string` and `mail_content = render_to_string('path/to/email_template.html', context)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the bug by adding this :

```
'html_email_template_name': 'password_reset_email.html'
```

to opts={} in save method

Comment: Could you please add your urls.py and explain even more detailed how your finished code looks? Also folder structure and maybe settings.py?